# Jquery $('.article.active').next Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, if-statement, addclass

I got something like a slider , at least it should be.But something is not working here is the code :

```
$('div.app').on('click' , function(){
var current = $('.article.active');
if(current.next('.article').length > 0)  {
    current.next('.article')
        .effect("slide" ,{direction:'left', mode:'hide'},1000)
        .addClass('active')
        .removeClass('hide');
    current.effect("slide",{direction:'right',mode:'show'},1000)
        .removeClass('active')

}   else {
         $('.article:first').removeClass('hide').addClass('active');
}


});
```

And the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/u4m0oLsc/.

Answer (score 2):

`var current = $('.article.active');` should be declared inside the click event function like:

```
$('div.app').on('click' , function() {
  var current = $('.article.active');
  ...
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4m0oLsc/2/)

Comment: Yes but that doesn't fix the slide effect.

Comment: Yea i'm not sure on the sliding effect. I don't have any experience with jquery-ui.